# Objective C - Error loading bundle

Tags: objective-c, nsbundle, theos, tweak

I'm working with a THEOS project. In my project, I want to use other frameworks or libraries with their's bundle resource (*.bundle) such as Google Plus framework. Because, this isn't a Xcode project so it hasn't **Copy Bundle Resources** section. I use NSBundle class to load bundle resource but I get this error

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The bundle “MyBundle” couldn’t
>   be loaded because its executable couldn’t be located."
>   UserInfo=0x15a308d0 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling
>   the bundle., NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle’s executable couldn’t
>   be located., NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “MyBundle” couldn’t be
>   loaded because its executable couldn’t be located.,
>   NSBundlePath=/var/mobile/Documents/MyBundle.bundle}

Here's my code

```
NSString *bundlePath = @"/var/mobile/Documents/MyBundle.bundle";
NSBundle *myBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath];
NSError *error;
BOOL loaded = [myBundle loadAndReturnError:&error];

NSLog(@"loaded: %@", (loaded ? @"TRUE" : @"FALSE"));
NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
```

I already try with other path and other bundle resource but I still get the same error

Comment: `frameworkBundle` isn't the same thing as `myBundle`, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot load resources from outside your application bundle or bundle container. "/var/ mobile/Documents" is inaccessible to your application.

The actual error you are getting is that the system could not load the *executable* for the bundle. `-loadAndReturnError:` is for loading code in that bundle. You seem to be loading a bundle that has resources, but not executable code.

Comment: I have `root` permission and my code running inside SpringBoard, therefore bundle source path will be `/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app`. I tried with `GooglePlus.bundle` but still get the same error message

Comment: "GooglePlus.bundle" is a resource bundle. It contains no executable. Calling `-loadAndReturnError:` is for loading executable binaries inside a bundle, not resources.

Comment: I see my error with `-loadAndReturnError:`, tks. But with original code `[NSBundle bundleWithPath:path]`, I get an error message `MyBundle.bundle (not loaded yet)`

Comment: Again, you have no code to load. These are resource bundles. After you instantiate the NSBundle using bundleWithPath, just start using resources from the bundle.

Comment: I already understand and I read Apple document again. I know `-loadAndReturnError:` use to load bundle's executable code. But my problem is that after I instantiate the NSBundle using bundleWithPath, I can't use its `*.png`, `*.nib`. On simulator and real device, my application always crash with error message like this `Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x156ad8b0 </var/mobile/Applications/E3E9EA24-B495-4C2F-8405-6BDCA408ABA7/AppTest.app/MyBundle.bundle/en.lproj> (not loaded)`

Comment: That path is a resource inside the bundle, not the bundle itself. Use the bundle methods to get paths to the resources in the bundle.